# Select File Depend on ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on web application save PDF file in table. PDF will store at PDFDATE folder and store path at column in Photo_table_1. This table has 2 columns (procid,doc_path). I used a code to display files in Gridview and Download it. This code shows all PDF files in PDFDATE folder. I looking for solution to show just specific pdf file depend on select statement( give procid then show its pdf file).

```
    protected void Button3_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("SIZE", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("TYPE", typeof(string));



        foreach (string strfile in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/pdfdate/")))
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strfile);
            dt.Rows.Add(fi.Name, fi.Length, fi.Extension);
        }
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName=="Download")
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octect-straam";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/PDFDATE/") + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is the specific procID going to come from? Does the user choose it somehow? Please be a bit clearer about the overall process.

Comment: User will add procID in text file and press button to show pdf file in gridview.

Comment: You need to write code to query files for the procid.

Comment: Right, i tried to write a select and store doc_path in String variable. And use this  variable as path. But i got error ('The directory name is invalid)

Comment: Is there only ever one PDF file for each procID? If so then you don't even need a gridview, they can just press the button and trigger the download immediately.

Comment: " i got error ('The directory name is invalid) "...ok but since we don't have any idea what code you used, what data was output into the variable, or anything about where your documents are stored, we cannot help you with that. Do some basic debugging - check what value was being created, and whether it was a valid path or not.

Comment: Each procid has one pdf file.

Comment: i need to get path from table and use this path in previews code

Comment: sure. But "I need" isn't a question or problem statement. Please show us what you have done so far to try and implement this. Then it will be easier for us to help you fix it. Thanks.

Comment: i have page with textbox which name is procid, button and gridview. also, there is  a folder which name is PDFDATE, contains PDF files. User will put procid in textbox(i.e 1) and press button then he will see pdf file in gridview. i tried to write a sql statement like (SELECT   doc_path FROM Photo_table_1 WHERE PROCID=procid.TEXT;. Then i used doc_path  as path in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(doc_path  ))) i got this error (The directory name is invalid)

Comment: Please use the "edit" button to add information and code to your question formatted nicely. Code in comments is not formatted and is hard to read, as I'm sure you can see for yourself. Also please make sure the code and information provided is sufficient to be a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means we need not only code but data (e.g. variable values) , and in your case we need to know something about your folder structure. But like i said also, **you** can easily check what value is coming for your path and see if it is correct for your filesystem.